# concatenate value to an existing env var using docker run

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Trying to concatenate a value to an existing environment variable in a docker container I'm starting.
for example - `docker run -it -e PATH=$PATH:foo continuumio/anaconda`

I am currently stuck at the point of trying to concatenate a value to the existing `PATH` environment variable that already exists in the container.

I am expecting to see the following value in the `PATH` environment variable of the container - `PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/scala/bin:/usr/local/sbt/bin:/usr/local/spark/bin:/usr/local/spark/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Instead I get this - `PATH=$PATH:foo`

using the `docker run` command. Is there anyway to achieve what I'm aiming at?

--EDIT--

I am executing the command from a windows 10 command line window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
docker run -it continuumio/anaconda /bin/bash -c "PATH=$PATH:foo exec bash"
```

This command launches `bash` in the container, passes it a command (`-c`) that appends to the existing `$PATH` and then replaces itself with a new `bash` copy (`exec bash`) that inherits the new `$PATH` value.

If you also want to execute a command in the updated shell, you can pass another `-c` option to `exec bash`, but note that quoting can get tricky, and that a trick is needed to keep a shell *open*:

```
docker run -it continuumio/anaconda /bin/bash -c "PATH=$PATH:foo exec bash -c 'date; exec bash'"
```

The small caveat is that the shell that is running when the startup command has finished is not the same instance as the one that ran the command (which shouldn't be a problem, unless your startup command made modifications to the *shell* state (such as defining functions, aliases, ...) that must be preserved).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The only way to set an environment variable with `-e` is if the value is known *ahead of time*, *outside* the container; **whatever you pass to `-e` must be a *literal* value - it cannot reference definitions *inside* the container**.

As an aside: If you ran your command on a Unix platform rather than Windows, the *current* shell would expand `$PATH`, which is also not the intent.

Comment: This is as thorough a response as I can ask for, thanks a lot.